# Dialog Up when soft keyboard Opens

Tags: android

In a Dialog, when the `EditText`gains focus and the soft keyboard opens, this soft keyboard moves the dialog up to the top of the activity.
I have set `adjustPan` for the dialog but it doesn't work. How can it be done?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?